# Moving images based on IPTC metadata in bash

Tags: bash, grep, metadata, xargs, exiftool

I am trying to reorganise images based on the species that is within an image. Among other information, the species name can be found in the IPTC metadata (see link to the [Inspector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm0Td.png)). I am attempting to do this in bash on macOS and have tried following code (with template species name and directory):

`find . -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "Species Name" | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ~/example/directory`

I have also tried using the `exiftool` package, where the relevant information is in the Subject tag:

`find . -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 exiftool -Subject | grep "Species Name" | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ~/example/directory`

However, I receive following error message, which I assume to be a result of a misuse of `grep` or the last `xargs`:

`mv: rename (standard input)
 to ~/example/directory(standard input)
: No such file or directory`

Any ideas what could fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The words `Species Name` don't appear to be in the metadata you show....

Comment: The species name in the metadata shown is 'Malayan Porcupine'. Depending on the species present in the image, this will change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exiftool can move and rename files based upon the file metadata and is much faster calling it once for an entire directory than calling it individually for each file in a loop ([Common Mistake #3](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M3)).

I believe you could use this command to do your sorting:
`exiftool -if '$subject=~/Species Name/i' -directory=~/example/directory .`

Breakdown:
`-if '$subject=~/Species Name/i'` Does a regex comparison of the `Subject` tag for the "Species Name".  I added the `i` at the end to do the comparison case insensitively, modify as desired.
`-directory=~/example/directory`  If the `-if` condition is met, then the file will be moved to the stated directory.

Comment: After running the suggested code, I get following message
`1 directories scanned; 503 files failed condition; 0 image files read`  
and running the code with the -v2 flag indicates that there is a syntax error. I have tried other options like 
`exiftool -if "${Keywords//[[:blank:]]/} =~ \W*MalayanPorcupine\W*\i" -directory=~/Desktop/image_data/malayan_porcupine .` but this doesn’t work as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Change the double quotes to single quotes to avoid bash interpreting the dollar sign as the beginning of a shell variable. Also, check which tag you actually want to use.  You mention `Subject` in your original post, which is where keywords would be located in XMP (IPTC Core) but `Keywords` in your comment (IPTC Legacy).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. Worth to mention that I've added the `-r` flag and changed `.` for a directory, as this will have to process files in subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `grep`'s output newline is interfering there, as you're using a clean `-0` pipeline, you should do so with `grep` -- in Linux it would be `grep -Z ...` (or `--null`), dunno if Mac OS's has a similar one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this hasn't helped. However what I have noticed is that `grep` does not return any pathways even with the -l and/or -Z flag. Instead it returns `(standard input)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which grep? The one in your first command should print each file name as it's being passed a list of file names by xargs, the one in your second command should print "standard input" since it's getting it's input from a pipe.